# Return the content of a cell in a Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm starting with Google App Script and I'm stuck trying to find a way to return the content of a cell inside my code.

Here's the code I want to edit :

```
function ListFldPdfs() {
  // replace FOLDER-ID with your folder's ID
  // replace SHEET-NAME with the name of the sheet that will hold the list
  var folderid = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(lastRow, 1).getValue();
  var myPDFfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderid);
  var thesheet = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX' // give a name to YOUR list sheet

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var newPDFsheet = ss.getSheetByName(thesheet); 
     if (!newPDFsheet) { 
       ss.insertSheet(thesheet, 0); 
       var newPDFsheet = ss.getSheetByName(thesheet) ;
  Logger.log(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName());
     }
  // clear all existing content
  newPDFsheet.clear();
  // append the header row

  // list all pdf files in the folder
  var mypdfs = myPDFfolder.getFilesByType(MimeType.PDF);
  // loop through found files in the folder
  while (mypdfs.hasNext()) { 
    var myfile = mypdfs.next(); 
    var fname = myfile.getName();
    var furl = myfile.getUrl();
    results = [ fname, furl, ];
    //Logger.log("results = "+results); // for de-bugging
    newPDFsheet.appendRow(results); 
       }
}
```

I've replaced the folder id with this in order to get the content from a cell :

```
  var folderid = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(lastRow, 1).getValue();
  var myPDFfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderid)
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work... Anyone could tell me what i'm missing ?

Comment: lastRow is undefined

Comment: How can i define it ? Or is there a way to point to a specific cell using A1 notation ? Something like "SHEETNAME!A1:B2"

Comment: `thesheet.getLastRow()`

Comment: SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was in a comment, on

```
var folderid = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(lastRow, 1).getValue();
```

`lastRow` is used but it has not being declared.

To declare it could use:

```
var lastRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow();
```

Another option is, instead of `getRange(lastRow, 1)` use `getRange('B2')`, assuming that `B2` holds the value that you want to assing to `folderid`

Comment: Thank you @Ruden, you solved my case !
I ended up using your getRange('B2') solution as I find it more elegant.